# Unable to render template "error"; resolver could not resolve to a file ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have already seen all the links that are already discussed for this topic but could not seem to be working for me, therefor I would like to open this discussion once more and show you my config files as well..

First of all my folder structure is like this:
[image]

So far I have module.config.php like this:

```
    return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',       
        ),
        'view_manager' => array(
            'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'album/album/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/album/album/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
                ),
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            )
        )
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an Application module where there is a file `view/error/404.phtml`. Remove the following lines from the **Album** module (so *not* the Application module):

```
'error/404'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
```

What happens is the Album module *overrides* the Application module with its configuration. The Album module refers to the error page which does not exists in the Album module (see, in the album there is no `view/error/404.phtml file`).

If you also removed the Application module, get it back from the skeleton application and everything will work again.

Comment: so desperated that something get fixes and another problem comes like Message:

    Route with name "album" not found

:S

Comment: If this fixed the problem, please open a new question and mark this as solved :) It's much easier for other users to find the answer to the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot

```
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
```

like that:

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to Album\Module.php

```
public function getConfig()
{
   return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}
```